# Cumulative count of unique strings for each id in a different column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (df_temp) which is like the following:

```
   ID1  ID2
0  A    X
1  A    X
2  A    Y
3  A    Y
4  A    Z
5  B    L
6  B    L
```

What I need is to add a column which shows the cummulative number of unique values of ID2 for each ID1, so something like

```
   ID1  ID2   CumUniqueIDs
0  A    X     1
1  A    X     1
2  A    Y     2
3  A    Y     2
4  A    Z     3
5  B    L     1
6  B    L     1
```

I've tried:

```
 dfl_temp['CumUniqueIDs'] = dfl_temp.groupby(by=[ID1])[ID2].nunique().cumsum()+1
```

But this simply fills CumUniqueIDs with NaN.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here! Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use `groupby()` + `transform()` + [`factorize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
In [12]: df['CumUniqueIDs'] = df.groupby('ID1')['ID2'].transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]+1)

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
  ID1 ID2  CumUniqueIDs
0   A   X             1
1   A   X             1
2   A   Y             2
3   A   Y             2
4   A   Z             3
5   B   L             1
6   B   L             1
```

Comment: once again out fast fingered me.  Good answer. +1

Answer (score 4):

By using `category`

```
df.groupby(['ID1']).ID2.apply(lambda x : x.astype('category').cat.codes.add(1))
Out[551]: 
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    1
6    1
Name: ID2, dtype: int8
```

After assign it back

```
df['CumUniqueIDs']=df.groupby(['ID1']).ID2.apply(lambda x : x.astype('category').cat.codes.add(1))
df
Out[553]: 
  ID1 ID2  CumUniqueIDs
0   A   X             1
1   A   X             1
2   A   Y             2
3   A   Y             2
4   A   Z             3
5   B   L             1
6   B   L             1
```